# I get error :ORA-00923 when I use over partition by

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new in oracle ,I want to use over partition by .my code is :

```
select  eff_date, count(1) OVER(PARTITION BY EFF_DATE) ,MAX( NAME)    
from  TBL_LCR_REP_PROFILE_DETAIL 
HAVING COUNT(1) =  43 AND IS_STANDARD = 0 ;
```

but I get error :

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 27
```

please help me

I want to fix this error :

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 27
```

Comment: `NAME   OVER (PARTITION BY EFF_DATE)`? I don't think this exists. Did you mean to match `OVER()` with `COUNT()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't make much sense to me. Either you want to use `count` in its analytic form (so you probably don't want `having` clause and lack `group by`), or as aggregation.

So:

```
select eff_date, name, count(*)
from tbl_lcr_rep_profile_detail
where is_standard = 0
group by eff_date, name
having count(*) = 43;
```

or

```
select eff_date, name, count(*) over ()
from tbl_lcr_rep_profile_detail
where is_standard = 0
```

---

Both queries might be modified, but - perhaps you should explain what you want to do. Saying that "want to use over partition by" doesn't help much. Why do you want to use it?

Comment: thank a lot but my result is nothing !!!!

Comment: You mean, queries don't return anything? Perhaps you should start over, step-by-step. First `select eff_date, name from tbl_lcr_rep_profile_detail`. If it returns data, add condition: `where is_standard = 0`. If there are rows returned, then add `count(*)` into `select` and `group by eff_date, name` - you should still see something. Finally, add `having count(*) = 43`. It presumes that there's `eff_date, name` combination in that table which is repeated EXACTLY 43 times. If there's none, well - query won't return anything.

Comment: please take a look again but I can not use group by with over partition ,I get new errors .

Comment: My previous comment is related to the 1st query I posted, the one without COUNT function in its analytic form. I suggest you try it first. If you aren't sure in what you're doing, you should really go step-by-step and "build" query, adding meaningful pieces to it. Don't go any further until previous step returns desired result.